# Can I easily use GSAP with ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, gsap

I am a .net programmer who is about to start a new project and would like to venture out into the world of open source software. After all my research I had settled for Angular.js and GSAP. But after reading how Angular.js 2.0 is going to be radically different from 1.3, I am beginning to lean towards ember.js. I've tried figuring this out myself, but I noticed that there isn't as much material out there for ember.js as there are for Angular.js. So my question is...

- Would I be able to easily integrate GSAP into an ember.js project? Do they play well together? Thanks!

Ps. The stacks I am planning on using is ember.js/Angular.js, GSAP, node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s nothing preventing you from using typical Javascript libraries in an Ember application. Depending what you’re trying to do with GSAP, you could look at [Liquid Fire](https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire), which is an Ember-centric animation addon for ember-cli.

Comment: Thanks Doyle. I'll take a look at Liquid Fire. ;0)